# Unity GameObject position z is mysteriously changed after object is created in script

Tags: c#, position, scrollview, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have once again problems with Unity. I can't spear much code due the level of secrecy agreement in the game I'm working on but I ran to this one annoying problem when running my code.

SO, I'm creating GameObjects in runtime when entering a certain view in the game. I have created a so called Reader for our game story which reads text from database, splits it to paragraphs, creates GameObject around that paraghraph text (setting text components etc. to it) and then adds that GameObject and its text to a story panel that shows all the objects as a scrollable view inside masked panel.

Hopefully you can keep up with my explanations :D

Everything works fine all the way to the point that the paragraphs are appearing correctly underneath the parent object (the view panel for the texts) and is shown correctly in the scene view, but... the problem is that, although i have made several checks in update loops, Unity just keeps giving random z position to the GameObjects setting them to 
[`position z = -350`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wolCk.png)

which makes them out of the player view and quite hard to read :D

I have debugged many times the position of the GameObjects in update giving it out z position 0 in every frame. This clearly doesn't mach the value the objects have in editor view during runtime...

Has anyone ran in to this kind of problem?

ps. I have treid to close and open Unity, load things again, nothing works.

oh and one thing to mention too is that to stretch the text to fit the size of text content and parent panel width I have used these as examples:
["Unity UI Tutorial - How to make a scrollable list" by rachetandclank3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUun2xW6FJ4)

Comment: and another link here as reference due to my reputation: 
http://mobile.folio3.com/creating-dynamic-scrollable-lists-with-new-unity-canvas-ui/

Answer (score 5):

Hmm... I somehow managed to fix this problem when I changed this:

```
this.paragraphObject.transform.localPosition.Set(
    this.paragraphObject.transform.position.x,
    this.paragraphObject.transform.position.y,0f);
```

to using this instead:

```
Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(
   this.paragraphObject.transform.position.x,
   this.paragraphObject.transform.position.y, 0f);

this.paragraphObject.transform.localPosition = newPosition;
```

hopefully this helps others that also struggles with this kind of problem.

Source to the solutions: [GameObject position.Set() not working](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/225729/gameobject-positionset-not-working.html)

Answer (score 1):

in Vector3 at z position try to change with `gameObject.transform.position.z`,

> replace gameObject with the object name which position is changed mysteriously.